# How do I make an HTML iFrame fit the whole page without needing to scroll?

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

I need to use an iFrame within another page, and I want to make it fit the entire web page that it's embedding without the need to scroll. So, how can I set the iFrame height to the height of the web page?

I tried just setting the iFrame height to 100%, but for obvious reasons, that did not work.

I'm sure the answer is simple, I'm better at the back end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
html,body{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
        iframe{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://blogger.com" name="otherSite"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please mark this question as solved wherever you want, so people don't have to spent time on this anymore. @Jake StBu

Answer (score 1):

To fit the iFrame on the whole webpage you can apply the width and height in vw or vh like width:100vw or height:100vh it will take the height or width of the view port.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. I was talking about making the iFrame fit all of the contents of the other site.

Comment: But this is not feasible because other site content can we larger or smaller we can not control that.

Comment: @Kailash yesy my answer...
It should work for any webpage.