# Iframe always showing vertical scroll in edge browser

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I'm using iframe in my application, iframe style with no scroll. And it is working fine in the Chrome browser. Whereas in the Edge browser always one vertical scroll bar is showing. Unable to remove it in the Edge browser.

Answer (score 0):

[DUPLICATE] [How do I make an HTML iFrame fit the whole page without needing to scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298533/how-do-i-make-an-html-iframe-fit-the-whole-page-without-needing-to-scroll/)
To get an iframe that takes the whole page without scrollbars You can try this :
Best regards.
Nicolas.

```css
html,body{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
        iframe{
            width:100%;
            height:100vh;
            overflow:hidden;
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            border:none;
        }
```

```html
<iframe src="https://blogger.com" name="otherSite"></iframe>
```

Comment: @karthikraja kandasamy If this is the answer you're looking for please mark it as solved.